# Why are the coefficients of the complementary function of a second order differential equation with complex roots conjugate pairs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Once I have the complementary function of a second order differential equation with complex roots; $y=Ae^{(a+bi)x} + Be^{(a-bi)x}$

I expanded this out to $e^{ax} ((A+B)\cos(bx) + i(A-B)\sin(bx))$

Apparently $A+B$ can be written as $C$ and $i(A-B)$ can be written as $D$ where $C$ and $D$ are real numbers as $A$ and $B$ are conjugate pairs. The textbook explains why they are conjugate by using an example question but I wanted to know more generally why the coefficients $A$ and $B$ are conjugate pairs. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

$y$ is a real function, $y=\bar y$. Comparing coefficients in
$$
Ae^{(a+bi)x}+Be^{(a-bi)x}=y(x)=\overline{y(x)}=\bar Ae^{(a-bi)x}+\bar Be^{(a+bi)x}
$$
gives directly $B=\bar A$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am not sure what the bar above the y means, sorry. This is probably because I am an A level student. Is there a simpler explanation?

Comment: It is one notation for the complex conjugate. In more operator oriented fields the hermitean adjoint is noted as $A^*$, for matrices that is $\bar A^T$, and that is sometimes also used for scalars, so that $\bar y=y^*$.