# Are one of the coefficients of the general solution of $y''+9y=0$ imaginary?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the second-order homogeneous equation
$$
y''+9y=0\tag{1}
$$
for this equation, the characteristic equation is $m^2+9=0$, implying $m=\pm3i$, and hence the general solution is
$$
y=c_1\cos3x+c_2\sin3x
$$
Now, since the general solution of
$$
ay''+by'+cy=0\tag{2}
$$
is given by
$$
y=Ae^{\alpha x}+Be^{\gamma x}
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ satisfy the characteristic equation of $(2)$, we have that the general solution to $(1)$ is also given by
$$
y=Ae^{3ix}+Be^{-3ix}\\=A\cos3x+iA\sin3x+B\cos3x-iB\sin3x\\=(A+B)\cos3x+i(A-B)\sin3x
$$
and so therefore, if $A, B \in\mathbb{R}$, then $i(A-B)\in\mathbb{C}$, and hence $c_2\in\mathbb{C}$, and I'm simply not sure whether or not this latter property holds. If anyone could confirm/elaborate, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2993757/115115 and possible dozens other prior questions on the same topic

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. We could have $A=B,$ in which case the solution is entirely real.

Effectively, our "general solution" is actually an infinite family of solutions. In this family, there are infinitely many solutions of the form $y=c\cos3x$ for some real $c,$ and infinitely many solutions of the form $y=c\cos3x+di\sin3x$ for some real $c$ and $d.$

**Added**: More generally, if we don't make the restriction that $A,B\in\Bbb R,$ then for any $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb C,$ $y=\alpha\cos3x+\beta\sin3x$ is a solution to the ODE.

Comment: $d$ could also be purely imaginary, for instance if $B=A^*$, giving a completely real solution (to the linear DE with real coefficients).

Comment: That's fair, although the OP was asking specifically about the case that $A,B\in\Bbb R.$